# Debugging Kibana backend Node.js code

Tags: node.js, kibana, kibana-4, node-inspector

How to debug [Kibana](https://github.com/elastic/kibana) backend source code?

I presume, `node-inspector` could be used. And some extra configuration needed for `package.json` file to run debugger at `npm start`. But, I can't figure out the correct configuration syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--debug bin/kibana --dev
```

If you want to break before starting:

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--debug --debug-brk" bin/kibana --dev
```

Alternatively, you can set the same variable when calling `npm start`:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--debug npm start
```

You will see:

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
```

You can then use the node inspector by running `node-inspector` and opening http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858.

If you are debugging a remote server, you can either run `node-inspector` on the server and forward port 8080 through SSH, or you can run `node-inspector` locally and forward port `5858` through SSH.

**EDIT**: As it was now mentioned in the comments, it might be necessary to edit the source and add `debugger;` at the beginning, otherwise breakpoints might not work correctly even when using `--debug-brk`. Not sure why, though.

Comment: It works! Thank you. But the code execution doesn't break on a breakpoint. Could you give me a hint why?

Comment: This is an issue I also sometimes struggle with when using node inspector, and sometimes the issue is an old node.js version either at the debuggee or the debugger, or an old node inspector version, or both...

Comment: Ok, I found why it didn't work for me. **First**, the debug port could change on Kibana restart. It changed to `5861` in my case. So, I used the following URL to access the debug console: [http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858](http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858). **Second**, you have to put `debugger;` on a new line before the source code you want to debug. Wait for 2-3 minutes for the console to load. Then, after it breaks you can add new breakpoints via the console web interface.

Comment: Yes, it breaks with `--debug-brk`. But when I add a new breakpoint and press `continue script execution` - nothing happens. So, I ended with using `debugger;` and `NODE_OPTIONS=--debug npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

add `$NODE_OPTIONS --no-warnings --inspect`

and start kibana server and access the link shown in the logs like this link "chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@521e5b7e2b7cc66b4006a8a54cb9c4e57494a5ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:5858/node" then you will find your backend code in the source tab and you can debug it like debuging frontend code.